# e bootstrap panel ul li element cant align in mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added the bootstrap  panel to some mobile responsive <**ul**> <**li**> part  its float right part cant move to right side  how can I fix it, look this image [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5ZwX.png)

I need to take thin some margin right ,  please help me to fix it.
Thanks.

```css
.panel-invoice ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-invoice li {
  float: left;
  color: #7c828b;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.panel-invoice li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.panel-pro .panel-body {
  padding: 9px;
  height: 66px;
}

.panel-pro .panel-heading {
  padding: 9px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.panel-amount {
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.panel-lines {
  border-top: 1px dotted #dad6d6;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.panel-total-amounts .height {
  color: #b89981;
}

.panel-marks {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-detils-profile">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel-pro">
      <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">Mahesh H


          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel-invoice">
              <ul>
                <li>Total bill
                </li>

                <li class="panel-right-side panel-amount" style="float:right;">$ 750.00
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-invoice">
              <ul>
                <li>Advance payments

                </li>

                <li style="float:right">$ 00.00
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div class="panel-lines">

              </div>
              <ul>
                <li><span class="panel-marks">Balance payments</span>


                </li>

                <li class="panel-total-amounts" style="float:right"><span class="height">$ 750.00</span>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>



  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw your result. It look well. So what is your expect result? Better describe it by image

Comment: Sir, i need some get is right side, its cant do it,look at image

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: im Currently  using `v3.3.7`

Comment: As we can see when run code snipet, your payment value actually in right side.

Comment: sir, look my image, i saw its working for the code snipet, but not work for me, look image its have right side is a big space , sir its my  big mistake im not mention its a mobile responsive , mistake in a mobile responsive

Comment: What browser are you testing with? If the code works in snipet, it should work in your project unless there are some diffences. And we only can play with this code in snipet to help you.

Comment: google chrome and Firefox

Comment: This code snippet works well on both browser so you should figure out what is difference between your code and this code snipet.

Comment: ok sir, thanks for the guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem you wont need to write any css code, all the style avaible on bootstrap itself, better to learn the bootstarp. Please read the doc here -> [bootstrap- documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/)

Here is the [JSFiddle answer for your problem](https://jsfiddle.net/kcxc67bz/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```